# How to draw arrow head in the middle of line D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I want to show arrow head in the middle of line.

```
svg.append("svg:defs").append("svg:marker")
.attr("id", "triangle")
.attr("refX", 6)
.attr("refY", 6)
.attr("markerWidth", 12)
.attr("markerHeight", 12)
.attr("orient", "auto")
.append("path")
.attr("d", "M 0 0 12 6 0 12 3 6")
.style("fill", "black");

svg.append('line').attr('x1',0).attr('x2',100).attr('y1',0).attr('y2',50).attr("marker-end", "url(#triangle)");
```

This code shows arrow head at the end of line but not in the middle.

If I change "marker-end" to *marker-mid* it not works neither.

How can I do this?